# Creation of Measle Chart / Defect Chart List Selection

Tags: list

Is it possible to create a "Choice" column which returns a value based upon selection of a coordinate on a specified image. I am trying to record the location of a defects across multiple parts. To do so, I'd like to allow the user to select a location on an overlaid image.

The user should be able to select multiple locations.

[image]

Thank you,
Brandon Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer this to closest I could guide you. Where are you trying to acheive this?
If Sharepoint on prem using SharePoint designer we can create clickable regions for an image.refer [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/seanearp/creating-an-image-map-in-sharepoint-designer-2010)!. Does the image change for each list item?
If it doesn't, then embed the image(with the clickable sections) in the page as shown and use jQuery to create the onclick events which would in turn show the choices accordingly.
Let me know if you want working example.(I didn't try it out but this is simillar to cascading dropdowns).